# Solana Airdrop: Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached

Tags: solana, airdrop, solana-cli

tried:

```
solana airdrop 1
solana airdrop 1 <address> --url devnet
solana airdrop 1 <address> --url https://api.devnet.solana.com
```

all returns this error:

```
Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached.
```

i can confirm that my cli config is set to devnet, also it affects my typescript function airdropSol() which returns an error:

```
Error: airdrop to GFfY2JVH2iB9gRmg7oKdwgGJcbXuhGu8vEsMY5yJryeq failed: Internal error
at Connection.requestAirdrop (/home/user/hellow_world/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3905:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Comment: devnet might be down. wait and try again later.

Comment: it's been already 2 days and same error still happen, my classmates projects were working properly tho, same code. can't figure out what might causes the problem, sad

Comment: gimme your account. i cna send you some token.

Comment: can you try different address

Comment: Tried with different address and same thing happen, thanks for the offer but i have sol for transactions, it's just my code requires the airdrop function for it generates new accounts

Comment: internal error means server cannot process the request. if you get response from the server that means your solana installation is correct. maybe your api address is blocked somehow. can you manipulate the ip address and try it again

Comment: or maybe try to install the solana latest version

Comment: tried reinstalling different versions of solana, no luck. just want to confirm, solana do blocking api requests from ip which requests airdrops too often? if so, is changing ip the only solution for this, is there by any chance i could contact them and explain my situation? :'(

Comment: Search how to change ip address in your os.

Comment: r u sure you are passing correct address

Comment: yeah, 100%. it used to work, but after a while it suddenly returns such error without any alteration made in the code

Answer (score 0):

Try running this

```
curl -v https://api.devnet.solana.com --resolve api.devnet.solana.com:443:139.178.65.155 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"requestAirdrop", "params":["<wallet pub key>", 1000000000]}'
```

more expannation - https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/4240/3028